# Help understanding a php function - the meaning of $array[]; the [] part

Tags: php, arrays, json, autocomplete

```
private function jsonArray($object)
{
  $json = array();

   if(isset($object) && !empty($object))
   {
      foreach($object as $obj)
      {
        $json[]["name"] = $obj;
      }
   }

   return $json;
}
```

We are grabbing an object, and if the conditional is met, we iterate over that object.
Then... I'm lost on this reading... :s

What's the meaning of the [] here?

```
$json[]["name"] = $obj;
```

Thanks in advance,
MEM

Comment: @All - So $json is: a multidimensional numeric indexed array, that contains an associative array, where the "name" key will correspond to $obj value. Precise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$json[]` adds an element at the end of the array (numeric index). It's the same as having the following code:

```
$array=array();
$i=0;
foreach($something as $somethingElse)
{
    $array[]=$somethingElse;
    //is equivalent, in some way, to
    $array[$i++]=$somethingElse;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's the equivalent to this:

```
$json[] = array('name' => $obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

It adds the contents of `$obj` to a new field in `$json` and there in the field `"name"`.

Little example:

```
$arr = array();
$arr[] = "Hello";
$arr[] = "World!";
```

Then, `$arr` will contain:

```
Array (
 0 => "Hello",
 1 => "World!"
)
```

Or, as in your example with another array in the field:

```
$arr = array();
$arr[]["text"] = "Hello";
$arr[]["text"] = "World!";
```

Becomes

```
Array (
 0 => Array (
  "text" => "Hello"
 ),
 1 => Array (
  "text" => "World!"
 )
)
```

Comment: With a zero-based index, I presume

Comment: Thanks a lot. The fact that $arr[] works like so, is due to php proper way of working?

Answer (score 2):

$json[] automatically creates a new element at the end of the array - here is an example:

```
$json[]["name"] = "object1";
$json[]["name"] = "object2";
$json[]["name"] = "object3";
$json[]["name"] = "object4";
```

And here is what it displays:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => object1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => object2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => object3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => object4
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The clear presentation of the output have help me understand it as well. (I was unable to var_dump because the php is loaded from an ajax call. :s)